# Excel VBA: Overflow Error within one line

Tags: excel, vba

I have this piece of code within a much larger code and it keeps giving me an overflow error on the line with R = ... I do not know how to fix this. Can anyone help?

```
Sub AutoUpdateF()
    Dim SG2 As Worksheet
    Dim SG3 As Worksheet
    Dim SG4 As Worksheet
    Dim SG5 As Worksheet
    Dim Totals As Worksheet
    Dim totalslastrow As Long
    Dim sg2lastrow As Long
    Dim sg3lastrow As Long
    Dim sg4lastrow As Long
    Dim sg5lastrow As Long
    Dim A As Double
    Dim B As Double
    Dim C As Double
    Dim D As Double
    Dim E As Double
    Dim W As Double
    Dim X As Double
    Dim Y As Double
    Dim Z As Double
    Dim V As Double
    Dim R As Double

    Set SG2 = Sheets("SG2")
    Set SG3 = Sheets("SG3")
    Set SG4 = Sheets("SG4")
    Set SG5 = Sheets("SG5")
    Set Totals = Sheets("Totals")

        Totals.Select
        totalslastrow = Totals.Cells(Rows.count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
        totalslastrow = totalslastrow + 1

        SG2.Select
        sg2lastrow = SG2.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        A = SG2.Cells(totalslastrow, 2)
        SG3.Select
        sg3lastrow = SG2.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        B = SG3.Cells(totalslastrow, 2)
        SG4.Select
        sg4lastrow = SG2.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        C = SG4.Cells(totalslastrow, 2)
        SG5.Select
        sg5lastrow = SG2.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        D = SG5.Cells(totalslastrow, 2)

        SG2.Select
        sg2lastrow = SG2.Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        W = SG2.Cells(totalslastrow, 3)
        SG3.Select
        sg3lastrow = SG2.Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        X = SG3.Cells(totalslastrow, 3)
        SG4.Select
        sg4lastrow = SG2.Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        Y = SG4.Cells(totalslastrow, 3)
        SG5.Select
        sg5lastrow = SG2.Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        Z = SG5.Cells(totalslastrow, 3)

        E = A + B + C + D
        V = W + X + Y + Z

        R = (Abs(E - V) / ((E + V) / 2)) * 100

        Totals.Select
        Totals.Cells(totalslastrow, 6).Value = R

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the values of E and V when it fails?

Comment: Not sure if it's the issue, but if ever `E + V` = 0, you'd have an error from dividing by 0. Also, you should probably assign the numbers to `Long` instead of `Double`.

Comment: Are you using `totalslastrow` where you should be using `sg2lastrow` etc ?  I can't follow what you're intending with that code...

Comment: thank you. I had the lastrow part named wrong and that corrected the problem!

Comment: Aside from the error pointed out by Tim, you are using the same sheet to get the sg#lastrow number, the SG2 should also change to the correct sheet you mean to work with.

Comment: I just fixed both of these errors, and now it is giving me repeated answers. Anyone know why?